# Why is protobuf 5-10x slower than memcpy for a list of bytes?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, protobuf-c

I've got two simple code blocks that have vastly different performance:

```
void testProto() {
  demo::Person* person = new demo::Person();
  person->set_data(data, BUFFER_LEN);
}

void testMemcpy() {
  demo::Person* person = new demo::Person();
  memcpy(memcpy_dest, data, BUFFER_LEN);
}
```

The proto file looks like this:

```
message Person {
  bytes data = 1;
}
```

According to the [Protobuf encoding docs](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#strings), setting length-delimited data seems as simple as copying data with a few header bytes. Why is it that the first function takes 5-10x more time than the second?

I made a full, easy to run example [here](https://github.com/theicfire/examples/tree/master/slow_proto).

Additional notes/context:

- Flatbuffers, and alternative to protobufs, does not have this problem
- [Here's my attempt](https://gist.github.com/theicfire/7125cc814d8904dd169fb981c770010a) at using a debugger. I can't step below the `Set` method.
- The reason this performance matters to me is that I’m converting some high throughput/low latency networking code over to protobufs. Since I’m running code like the above multiple times per packet, protobufs significantly hurts performance.
- I’m running at -O3, but even at -O0, there’s still a huge performance difference
- Function call overhead is not the problem because the poor performance scales with the size of the data. Function calls is just a constant overhead.
- I’ve tried a variety of ways to ensure that the memcpy is not optimized away (-O0, using the array). I’m pretty confident that the memcpy is not optimized away.
- I tried malloc inside of `testMemcpy`. That slowed things down a bit, but it's still at least 5x worse.
- I tried this on a Macbook M1 and Ubuntu Intel machine

Comment: Are you using optimised code?

Comment: Yes, you can see that in the example I've linked. I'm running -O3.

Comment: memcpy is generally implemented as a compiler intrinsic, while set_data is layers of out-of-line function calls. Does either one have *problematically* slow performance?

Comment: An inlined memcpy of known size and correct alignment can copy perhaps 8 or 16 bytes at a time.

Comment: All relevant details need to be in the question itself not in external links

Comment: Problematically slow: Yes, I'm replacing some high-throughput networking with protobufs and I'm finding that this is a bottleneck.

Comment: What is the `memcpy` copying and to where? It's clearly not a `demo::Person`. Perhaps the `memcpy` is just optimized away because noone looks at the result?

Comment: Function calls: That likely is not the problem because the poor performance scales with the size of the data. Function calls is just a constant overhead. I'll update the description to clear that up.

Comment: The code is not optimized away. Here's how I know why: Running with -O0 still has the same 5-10x difference in performance. In addition, regardless of what I do with the memcpy to make it not optimized away, it's still fast.

Comment: I've taken many of these guesses myself :). No, swapping the order does not change the outcome.

Comment: It seems like there's something in the *implementation* of protobufs that is not simply a memcpy. I just don't know what, though. I tried attaching a debugger but it didn't go deep enough to give me a helpful answer. I may try again now that I have a simple example though.

Comment: Also responding to @BoP - why would protobufs not be able to have the same benefits of 8 or 16 bytes at a time?

Comment: Looking inside the generated protobuf header it looks like it does quite a lot. I think the answer to why it's slower is in there somewhere.

Comment: @TedLyngmo yeah I've tried digging into the protobuf code but it's pretty challenging. Ultimately there's a `SetBytes` call that just calls `Set`, and I lose the trail there because there are so many `Set` functions.

Comment: @theicfire - I am just guessing here, but adding a header to the protobuf would make the  rest of the copying unaligned. And not being inlined would lose the advantage of having a known constant size. `testMemcpy` has all the advantages.

Comment: Protobuf is a lot more than just byte copying. For example, your memcpy already has a buffer (static!) to copy into. If I modify your benchmark so memcpy also has to allocate a place to store the bytes, like protobuf does, then the difference becomes much smaller. Still, proto is ~2x slower than memcpy - or in concrete terms, about 127 microseconds slower per iteration. Given that it also manages an allocator arena, varint encodes length, and tracks other message headers, this seems somewhat reasonable. If your bottleneck is copying single byte buffers around, protobuf is not the fastest.

Comment: @GManNickG thanks for the idea! I thought about this too but wasn't able to see what you're seeing. I tried `std::vector<uint8_t> dest(BUFFER_LEN)` and copying to `dest.data()`, and still see a 5-10x difference. What changes did you make?

Comment: fwiw protobuf's arena allocation doesn't help: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/arenas

Comment: @BoP humm, thanks for the insight. I added `+1`, and `+2` to the memcpy to try to prevent that (I think that would?). It's still 5-10x faster than protobuf.

Comment: @theicfire Let's move to a chat and I can give you some profiling tips. Wish this thing would pop up with the "want to start a chat?" thing, though...

Comment: @GManNickG how do I start a chat? I've never used chat.stackoverflow.com before!

Comment: Well, usually if you reply back and forth enough it just gives you a link, but in this case I guess not. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240296/why-is-protobuf-5-10x-slower-than-memcpy-for-a-list-of-bytes

Comment: With the help of GManNickG, we found out that the main issue with my demo is that memory is not being freed in `testProto`. Freeing that memory results in a 4x speedup. It's still unclear to me why protobufs is slower than memcpy (and gets even slower the bigger the message), but the 4x improvement is enough for me at the moment!

Answer (score -1):

The code in your benchmark is invalid. The program is ill-formed.
If it wasn't, the [[as-if rule]](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.abstract#:as-if_rule) would apply.
There is no *observable* behavior differences between calling your `testMemcpy()` function, and doing nothing at all. (Besides allocating memory that cannot be dealocated; That can be ignored, it's undefined behavior).

Comment: We discussed this in the comments. This is true, but even if it's correctly formed such that we ensure `testMemcpy` is not optimized out, the performance difference persists. There's something else going on.

Comment: I also mentioned this in the question: "I’ve tried a variety of ways to ensure that the memcpy is not optimized away (-O0, using the array). I’m pretty confident that the memcpy is not optimized away."

Comment: @ViralTaco_ Where is the undefined behavior in the given problem? Posting an answer that says, without demonstration, "the code is invalid" is not useful.

Comment: -O0 doesn't change the standard. There is NO OBSERVABLE difference in behavior.  Even if the compiler generates assembly, and it does get executed, and that assembly is x86-64, the processor will be able to optimize useless instructions away. (however, that's, massively, off-topic). My point was: you cannot use that code as a benchmark. Please: 0) Either deallocate the memory or don't dynamically allocate it. 1) Implement observable behavior, so you can measure something.
@GManNickG example of what? I explained the reason, in parentheses, at the end. It's unrelated to the question.

Comment: "The program is ill-formed." and "it's undefined behavior" have actual meaning. The problem appears well-formed to me (and my compiler), and contains no undefined behavior that I see.

Comment: Is it well-formed? What's the behavior of a program with variables for which the lifetime ends after program execution does? This is a genuine question. I don't remember, but I believe (if my memory serves me right) the standard mentions it, somewhere (might be in program execution [termination?], rather than object lifetime). The point is: why is it dynamically allocated, and why is that memory then left to rot? It's (likely) a programming error.

Comment: @ViralTaco_ You're allowed to leak whatever you want, even things with destructors, permitted you do not rely on those destructors to induce well-defined behavior (e.g. a destructor that sets some index that some other destructor uses to go into an array). Either way, we live in the Real World and this doesn't explain the latency discrepancy of the produced binary in any concrete terms.

Comment: I did explain the latency difference. First, in `testProto()` you have a heap allocation, then you have a construction, then a dereference through the `this` to call a (non const) method, then you have a copy taking place. in the `testMemcpy` you have nothing whatsoever, there is no observable behavior produce by running that function, it is (can be) a noop. Fine, you win, I'll write a benchmark.